# Como resuelvo este código?

Tags: python

Pregunta 1
Escriba una función de nombre `promedio_std()`. La función debe recibir una lista de números llamada lista, y debe retornar retornar el promedio de ellos, junto con su desviación estándar.

Hint 1: La desviación estándar corresponde a la raíz de la suma de los cuadrados de las
diferencias de cada elemento respecto al promedio, divididos por la cantidad de elementos.

Hint 2: Recuerda que puedes retornar dos valores `x` e `y` utilizando la notación**

Intenté con este pero no me sirve :( , el `promedio_std(lista)` debió entregar `61.55` y `29.006`, pero entregó `0.7` y `47.55`, lo necesito para finalizar un curso

```
def promedio_std(lista):
  x = 0
  y = 0
  suma = 0
  media = sum(lista) / len(lista)
  total = 0.0
  for i in lista:
    suma = suma + i
    total = total + (i - media) ** 2
    y = (total) ** 0.5
    x = suma / len(lista)
    return (x,y)

# debes modificar todos los elementos de la función
# cuidando el retorno, nombre y argumentos
```

Comment: se más descriptivo, decir "no me sirve" no ayuda a diagnosticar el problema

Comment: Y cuales son los datos de prueba??

Comment: Tienes un `return` dentro del `for`, ¿o está mal indentando?

Comment: Tal como lo tienes, con el return dentro del for, estás retornando en la primera iteración del bucle. Las líneas que calculan `x` `y` y retornan deberían estar fuera del bucle

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema en el código? "Como resuelvo este código?" no es un título descriptivo. Pulsa en [edit] y haz las modificaciones correspondientes.

Answer (score 0):

Como no pones un ejemplo para comprobar el resultado utilicé el ejemplo de [khanacademy.org](https://es.khanacademy.org/math/probability/data-distributions-a1/summarizing-spread-distributions/a/calculating-standard-deviation-step-by-step)
en el que la lista es 6,2,3,1

El código parecido al tuyo (así lo haría en **C**) sería:

```
def promedio_std(lista):
    media = sum(lista) / len(lista)
    datos = []
    for x in lista:
        n = (x - media) ** 2
        datos.append(n)
    suma = sum(datos)
    res1 = suma / len(lista)
    return media, res1 ** (1/2)    #   Ojo al paréntesis de la raíz cuadrada
```

Como hablas de finalizar un curso, en pyton lo haría aprovechando las ventajas de **python**:

```
def promedio_std(lista):
    media = sum(lista) / len(lista)
    res = (sum((x - media) ** 2 for x in lista) / len(lista)) ** (1/2)   #   Ojo al paréntesis de la raíz
    return media, res
```

Para llamar a la función e imprimir con 2 decimales:

```
l = [6,2,3,1]
resultado = promedio_std(l)
print(f'Media = {resultado[0]  :.2f}  Desviación estandar= {resultado[1] :.2f}')
```

El resultado:

```
Media = 3.00  Desviación estandar= 1.87
```

Todas las explicaciones matemáticas están en la página del vínculo.